# Golang removes double slashes and fires GET instead POST requests , how can I skip this in Cloud Functions?

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have a Cloud function where the same endpoint accepts 2 methods: POST and GET.
My problem is when the client tries to upload a multipart/form-data file through a POST request and by mistake the url contains double slashes, Golang redirects to GET method.

I have looked some replies where they talk about the Clean method https://golang.org/src/path/path.go?s=2443:2895#L74. And how the Mux under the hod is redirecting to GET.

Is there any way where I can check if that request has been redirected? so I can decide if the client has typed double slashes send a 400 Response for example instead the response from the logic in the GET method. I can't find that info in the headers. `fmt.Printf("%+v", r)`

Is there any way to skip the Clean method and accept the double slashes?.

Endpoint: `https://google.com/hello/folder/folder//image.jpg`

```
package test

func Hello(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    switch r.Method {
    case "GET":     
         //some logic here
          return 
    case "POST":
        //some logic here
         return
    default:
        fmt.Fprintf(w, "Sorry, only GET and POST methods are supported.")
        return
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Go doesn't redirect to GET method, Go redirects to a different, non-double URI with the 301 status code. It is the client that then ought to honor that instruction and resend the request to the new URI, it is also up to the client what the method it will use for the new request. And it is my understanding, although I may have just misinterpreted the rfc, that a client should not change the method from non-GET to GET when the status is 301.

Comment: @MuffinTop Unless I'm missing something the path cleaning *is* done by the [router](https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go?s=72906:72974#L2342).

Comment: Thanks @mkopriva, yes I can see with Curl in verbose mode what is happening behind scenes. In fact is the client(Curl) is doing two requests.

Comment: @mkopriva: from [RFC 7231 6.4.2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.4.2): *"For historical reasons, a user agent __MAY change the request
      method from POST to GET__ for the subsequent request.  If this
      behavior is undesired, the 307 (Temporary Redirect) status code
      can be used instead."*

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Thank you. It appears I was reading the rfc that the search engine spat out at me first, which seems to be more than a decade older than the one you're linking. [rfc 2616 10.3.2](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-10.3.2) *"When automatically redirecting a POST request after receiving a 301 status code, some existing HTTP/1.0 user agents will **erroneously** change it into a GET request."* My bad.